# Communication between one Activity and many Fragments through interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know there are many similar questions and answers here about this subject, but what I ask is slightly different.

I have four `Fragment`s and each one extend a `BaseFragment`. I'd like to add a listener to each `Fragment` so when an event fires to my `Activity` all the `Fragment`s will get notified about it.

I tried by declaring an interface :

```
public interface OnClearButtonListener {
     boolean onClearButtonPressed();
}
```

let my abstract `BaseFragment` class to implement it :

```
public abstract class BaseTabsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnClearButtonListener{
```

and I have added the interface in my `Activity` :

```
private OnClearButtonListener clearButtonListener;
```

but now I guess I need to somehow "connect" those two components so when I call from `Activity` then `Fragment`s will run `onClearButtonPressed()`

But I'm not sure how I can do it since I use a `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager` and the code for the initialization of it is :

```
private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new MyTabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(TagsFragment.newInstance(), "TAGS");
    adapter.addFragment(PeopleFragment.newInstance(), "PEOPLE");
    adapter.addFragment(CompaniesFragment.newInstance(), "COMPANIES");
    adapter.addFragment(JobsFragment.newInstance(), "JOBS");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
}
```

Comment: did u try implementing the interface in all the fragments that u want to receive the callbacks

Comment: @cricket_007 nope, the button belongs to the Activity. Unless you meant something else...

Comment: Just keep references to all fragments and call `onClearButtonPressed` on them

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I was thinking of something else

Comment: You might consider switching to using Events in your code because it decouples your classes; through the Publisher/Subscriber design pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity you hold a list like this

```
private List<OnClearButtonListener> clearables;
```

Make each Fragment implement that interface (through a parent class, or otherwise) and as you add to the adapter, you need that same instance added to the list.

```
BaseFragment f =  TagsFragment.newInstance();
clearables.add(f);
adapter.addFragment(f, "TAGS");
f = PeopleFragment.newInstance();
...
```

When you click on the button, loop over that list and call the onClearButtonPressed action

Refer: [Observer pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more `as you add to the adapter, you need that same instance added to the list.` ?  I  add each fragment like : `adapter.addFragment(TagsFragment.newInstance(), "TAGS");` how am I going to add that instance to the list ? Thanks!

Comment: Cool ! Thanks a lot and for the reference too!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use greenrobot EventBus for that purpose.

First you define a event:

```
public class OnClearButtonEvent {

    public final String message;

    public OnClearButtonEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

then in activity :

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(OnClearButtonEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

and in onStart and on Pause you un/register eventbus receivers

and in baseFragment:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new OnClearButtonEvent());
```

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

If you use RxJava it would be better to use RxEventBus

Comment: I think, that is the best and the most convenient approach to implement the callbacks. Try out this method instead of traditional callbacks. For more information check out [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).